# The minimum over all possible graph with n vertices of the multiplication of the clique and anticlique number is less than n

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

This is a question from the textbook by Nesetril Matousek which I quote here directly but rewrite slightly:

"For a graph G let us put f(G) = α(G)·ω(G), (ω(G) denotes the maximum number of vertices of a complete subgraph of G, and α(G) is the maximum number of vertices of an independent set in G) and let us define f(n) be the minimum of f(G) over all possible G with n vertices.

For natural numbers n,k, 1 < k ≤ n/2 we define a graph Cn,k: We begin with Cn i.e., a cycle of length n, and then we connect by edges all pairs of vertices that have distance at most k in Cn. Use these graphs (with a judicious choice of k) to prove that f(n) < n for all n ≥ 7. "

I guess my question is how do I even start to think about this problem because it's not intuitive to me at all if I want to do an induction on n. So can someone give me hints on how to solve this problem.

Comment: $\omega(G)\alpha(G)$ is the product of two integers.  If it has to be less than $7$ there aren't a lot of choices.  I don't know the answer to this, but I'd start by considering how to make a $C_{n,k}$ with both these numbers small.

Comment: I think I understand that part but now I think the problem is how to generalize the approach because I randomly draw some edges between the vertices after drawing the cycle to make f(n) < n for n = 7 but it doesn't makes intuitive sense to generalize it considering n=7 case.

Comment: You know $\omega(G)\geq2$ so you have to arrange for $\alpha(G)\leq3$

Comment: Have you considered trying to use the hint in the book? Maybe that would be a way to start to think about the problem? The authors tell you that the examples you're looking for are of the form $C_{n,k}$. Well, what are the clique and anticlique numbers of $C_7$? $C_8$? $C_9$? $C_{10}$? $C_{11}$? What are the clique and anticlique numbers of $C_{8,2}$? $C_{10,2}$?

Comment: Did you read the definition of $C_{n,k}$? It is not $C_n$ plus some random edges. The definition tells you exactly which edges to add to $C_n$ to get $C_{n,k}$.

Comment: I guess the intuition that i have is that for the minimum graph, you fix the w(G) = 2 first, which is given at the start when you form a Cn and then you draw edges between the vertices, such that the maximum distance between any 2 vertices is k, to obtain α(G) < n/2. I guess looking at @bof tells me that if you be careful to not draw edges between vertices such that it does not give you a triangle(i.e k =2), then it would satisfy the condition α(G) < n/2. Okay I think I see it now. Thank you so much for the help!